# How can I stop my shower doors from hitting one another and making an awful noise?

Tags: doors, shower

I have glass doors in the shower of my master bathroom and when I open and close the doors the screws hold the panes of glass to the runners are bumping into one another and making an awful noise.  I have the similar doors in the guest bathroom that are quiet as a mouse so I know there is a fixable problem, I'm just not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

Please take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAxupy5CTFo&feature=youtu.be) to see the problem in action:

Please take a look at [this photo album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTEzW.jpg) to see the pieces involved:

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem?  Assuming it is the bottom piece in the photos, does anyone know what that piece is called and/or where I can purchase a replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell. I would slowly operate the doors a few times and try to see where something might be contacting another piece. I don't think the top brackets are touching each other unless somehow the screws had losened. The top rail should keep the apart.

The spacer on the bottom I think might be the issue. The outside door looks pretty low. The top rail might have sagged a little or was not installed level and the outside door might be hitting it as it passed over it. Or possibly some sort of deposits have built up on the bottom.

You should be able to raise the outside door by removing it and repositioning the screws in the bracket. It differs by model but I haven't seen a set of doors that don't have some adjustment. When the doors are removed also make sure that bottom plastic spacer is clean and properly installed.

If you do this, wear shoes, a long sleeve shirt, gloves and safety glasses in case the glass breaks.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know the spacer at the bottom is called and where I can buy a replacement.  I couldn't find a match in my previous searches.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the inside door is not completely in the track. It's possible that the wheels are worn out and therefore allowing the tops of the door to come closer together than they should.

It also looks like the top rail might be bent down. Measure the height of the opening at each end and also the middle. If the middle is lower than the ends, some careful bending might be in order.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of either of those things, I will take a look next chance I get...

Comment: @Michael I don't know what it's called but you'll need to contact the door manufacturer and get a replacement part for your model. Helps if you already know the make and model.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY I actually don't know the make or model.  I will take a look when I get home.  Any idea where to look for that information?  I'm worried from what I have seen thus far that there isn't any distinguishing marks on it?

Comment: @Michael I don't think you'll find any markings that indicate brand. Only a few companies that I know of make frameless sliding bypass doors. You can look through their products and see if you find a match. Look for a set that has the same top rail and towel bar designs. Ooops looks like I replied to the wrong answer.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY ... You mention "only a few companies that you know of".  Would you mind telling me that list so I can start doing some research?

Comment: @Michael do a search on the websites for retailers near your area and see what they offer. Kohler makes a few under different names.